# Can you optimize this code? T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Essentially I have three fields and I am creating a new one which is the three combined making a mailable address; problem being some fields contain null values and adding myString to a null just produces a null in sql.

So this is my code, can anyone make it any cleaner? It's still looking pretty butch!

```
  UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[Account]
  SET [Billing Street] = CASE
  WHEN [(Billing Address 1)] is null and [(Billing Address 2)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 3)]
  WHEN [(Billing Address 1)] is null and [(Billing Address 3)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 2)]
  WHEN [(Billing Address 2)] is null and [(Billing Address 3)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 1)]
  WHEN [(Billing Address 1)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 2)] + ' ' + [(Billing Address 3)]
  WHEN [(Billing Address 2)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 1)] + ' ' + [(Billing Address 3)]
  WHEN [(Billing Address 3)] is null THEN [(Billing Address 1)] + ' ' + [(Billing Address 2)]
  ELSE [(Billing Address 1)] + ' ' + [(Billing Address 2)] + ' ' + [(Billing Address 3)]
  END
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for storing this in 3 separate fields to begin with?

Comment: The data comes from an Input file which we do all sorts of magic with so it needs to remain untouched

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `isnull` and `ltrim` to remove any leading whitespace:

```
update [mydb].[dbo].[Account]
set [Billing Street] = ltrim(isnull([(Billing Address 1)], '') +
                       isnull(' ' + [(Billing Address 2)], '') +
                       isnull(' ' + [(Billing Address 3)], ''))
```

Comment: +1 - deleted mine which was essentially the same, just using coalesce.

Comment: Nice work! The braket after the first parameter of the last isnull tripped me up breifly, but thats sweet as a nut, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If both old and new columns are going to coexist, you'd be better creating a computed column - that way, they never get "out of sync" with each other.

Take Andomars statement, and change it to read:

```
ALTER TABLE Account ADD
  [Billing Street] AS LTRIM...
```

Where LTRIM... continues as in Andomar's answer